# using nosql database as a replacement for sql server

Tags: c#, sql-server, nosql

I'm developing website that (if successful) its going to have a rapidly growing database (maybe terabytes or more). up to now I have always used sql server and didn't know anything about nosql.
I just found out about nosql doing research about the database size, and now I'm not sure if it will fullfil my needs. will I have the same power that I had with sql-server?

my question may seem silly as I'm a newbie in nosql but I just wanted to know if it doesn't support sql queries. how can we do something like:

```
select *, (select name from cities where id = cityid) from users
```

how to join tables? use something like stored procedures, views or things like these?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thats a big question. NoSQL is a broad term pretty much used to describe a bunch of non relational data stores. They can range from MongoDB, RavenDB (which are document stores) to things like Redis and other variants of key/value stores. They all operate very differently to SQL relational models (and the resulting T-SQL).

Document databases like Mongo or Raven typically have a C# driver that (in most cases) allows you to use LinQ queries across the datastore (Mongo example here [on this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4955357/mongodb-c-sharp-query-expression-how-to) and a RavenDB example [on their documentation page](http://ravendb.net/docs/2.0/client-api/querying)). They are all specific to their engine and different.

All these engines are not specifically designed to address the 'space' issue you are describing but rather try and have a low friction way of interacting with a datastore, in a fast way. All these data stores will still grow in size in the same way SQL does when throwing massive amounts of data at it. SQL Server will handle massive databases, as will most of the document stores and other NoSQL variants. To be honest, I'd trust SQL Server more than the newer NoSQL stores simply because it has been field tested for longer however as already stated, these document stores (and other stores like Apache Cassandra) can all handle large volumes of data. My only suggestion is to look at how you want to query the data. Document stores typically dont have the concepts of relational integrity like foriegn keys and so normalisation rules do not apply. In addition, you need to assess your reporting needs as SQL typically has an advantage in this area with more tooling. You can also choose a hybrid approach using SQL for your relational data and document stores for other object blobs and the like.

I would suggest looking into how you want to access your data first and then assess which one best suits your needs. One thing to note too is that SQL has some great features but often only in the enterprise versions. This costs a lot. Document databases tend to cost a LOT less for licencing, some being free, with many companies offering hosting so removing the need for you to worry about it. Finally, if going with SQL, I would suggest looking into sharding approaches from the very beginning given the amount of data you will be processing as this will make it much more manageable and also allow better query performance.

Comment: Yeah pretty much echoes my sentiments, in work, we use a hybrid and the really important data gets written to SQL

Answer (score 0):

I've used MongoDB quite a bit.  Id suggest signing up for a sandbox account on Mongolabs and playing around with it.  There is an excellent C# driver for it too.  NoSql is not really relational although you can relate documents via Ids.  In your example you'd store an array of cities (if I am reading your example clearly) against the User document and query that or vice versa.  There's less of a concern on data repetition because storage concerns aren't as important as they used to be.  I write my scripts (equilivent of stored procs) using JavaScript and run it directly against Mongo, its incredibly flexible and powerful.  Of course if you have tons of related objects, perhaps a relational database is your best bet.