# How to run any mongodb query from C#

Tags: c#, mongodb

I want to  run this mongodb query from C#:

```
db.Stories.find({_id: ObjectId("52318492c28f7c19d4270c7f")},
                {Chapter:
                     {$elemMatch:{
                           ChapId:ObjectId("52318629c28f7c1ec4515000")

                           }}
})
```

Comment: You have to be more specific and show your difficulty =) makes it easy for us to help you =)

Answer (score 1):

Try to make something like this:

```
var server = MongoServer.Create("mongodb://localhost:27020");
var database = server.GetDatabase("someDb");

var collection = database.GetCollection<Type>("someCollection");
var searchQuery = Query.GT("myfield", 10).LT(20);
var list = collection.Find(searchQuery);
```

Reference: [MongoDB C# Query expression (How to?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4955357/mongodb-c-sharp-query-expression-how-to)

Comment: what does Query.GT mean

Comment: It means "greater than" =)

Answer (score 0):

What does Query.GT mean 
My collection like this 
And i want to get The chapcontent in a chapter by chapid

```
"AuthorName" : "From",
        "CateName" : "biết chết liền",
        "Chapter" : [ 
            {
                "ChapContent" : [ 
                    {
                        "ImgUrL" : "../Upload/Stories/523675fec28f7c04b088afd6/52367611c28f7c04b088afd7/12613_617411151612439_796025785_n.jpg",
                        "Page" : 1,
                        "PageId" : ObjectId("52367612c28f7c04b088afd8")
                    }, 
                    {
                        "ImgUrL" : "../Upload/Stories/523675fec28f7c04b088afd6/52367611c28f7c04b088afd7/21453_617411254945762_2771189_n.jpg",
                        "Page" : 1,
                        "PageId" : ObjectId("52367612c28f7c04b088afd9")
                    }, 
    "DatePost" : ISODate("2013-09-16T03:07:42.096Z"),
    "Description" : "dsngdsfhgdsjhfgds",
    "FirstCharacter" : "b",
    "LastModify" : ISODate("2013-09-16T03:07:42.096Z"),
    "Status" : 1,
    "StoryName" : "biết ai",
    "Title" : "ai biêt",
    "_id" : ObjectId("523675fec28f7c04b088afd6")
```

Comment: It means "greater than" =)

Comment: Whats are the keys for you? Date and title? You have to search with filters (inside Find(...)) and deserialize result.